# One-to-one with preload relations in Ext JS 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm trying to setup a working one-to-one relation in Ext JS 6 that can be preloaded with the data of the referenced object(s).

This means that i should be able to define a class `Foo` and a class `Bar` that references `Foo` and then do `b = Ext.create(Bar, data)` in such a way that `b.something` contains a `Foo` object initialized with data.

Reading the doc [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) it seems quite simple, except that it does not work:

```
data = {'address': {'address': 'foo', 'city': 'foo', 'state': 'foo'}}
u = Ext.create('User', data)
u.getAddress()
none
```

The issue is also discussed [here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?298845-Has-One-Association-in-Model-not-working-in-Ext-js-5) but the proposed solution seems not to work in Ext JS 6.

Do someone have a working example in Ext JS 6 or a general solution?

P.S. to the overzealous moderator: this is **NOT** a duplicate of any similar question regarding Ext JS 4.* or Ext JS 5 because they have a different implementation of the relations therefore those solutions won't work.

Comment: Does this help? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12up

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.model.Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    schema: {
        namespace: 'Fiddle.model'
    }
});

Ext.define('Fiddle.model.User', {
    extend: 'Fiddle.model.Base',

    fields: [{
        name: 'address',
        reference: 'Address'
    }],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        idParam: null,
        url: 'user.json'
    }
});

Ext.define('Fiddle.model.Address', {
    extend: 'Fiddle.model.Base'
});


var user = Ext.create('Fiddle.model.User', {
    id: 1
});

user.load({
    callback: function(rec) {
        console.log(rec.getAddress().getData())
    }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12up

Comment: A note here: the difference with the extjs 5 examples  seems to be that you have to define a schema

Comment: @RiccardoCagnasso: I'm not sure, look at this one: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12ut

Comment: in my application i couldn't make it work until i defined a schema. With this level of documentation and the inherent non-debuggability of the high-events-and-callback-based extjs, it's more magic than computer programming

Comment: You don't _need_ the schema. It's required because you're using a relative namespace - the reference "Address" - and you're using the Fiddle. In an app, the namespace would have a default. And this is documented at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/core_concepts/data_package.html#Schema - but yes, the documentation isn't that good.

Comment: I can never figure out if extja is underdocumented or if the documentation is just horribly organized.